# Remove tick labels but not tick marks but preserve distance beween ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to remove tick labels but keep the tick marks and keep my ticks consistently spaced. I have tried using both ax.tick_params(labelleft='off') and ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,100,10), " ") but using either of these options rescales my y-axis, and I do not want this to happen.

```
a1 = plt.subplot(121, adjustable='box')
a1.plot(on[:,0], on[:, 1], linewidth=0, marker=markerz[i], color=kolor[i], ms=mymark)
a1.minorticks_on()
a1.set_yticks(np.arange(0,100,10))

a2 = plt.subplot(122, adjustable='box')
a2.plot(on[:,0], on[:, 1], linewidth=0, marker=markerz[i], color=kolor[i], ms=mymark)
a2.minorticks_on()
a2.tick_params(labelleft='off')
a2.set_yticks(np.arange(0,100,10))
```

This is what my plot actually looks like. I want certain subplots to share certain axes. I am trying to accomplish that by removing certain tick labels. I want to be able to remove tick labels without rescaling the tick spacing.
[image]

Comment: When inquiring about some undesired behaviour, this needs to be reproducible for others. See [mcve]. So please update your question with such a runnable example and clearly state how the output looks like and what is unexpected about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set empty ticks to your plots like this:

```
y_ind = np.arange(0,100,10)

plt.yticks(y_ind,['']*len(y_ind))
```

If you do not want your y-axis to be scaled again, then you can set the y-axis scale:

```
plt.ylim((y_ind[0],y_ind[-1]))
```

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

d1 = np.random.rand(100)
d2 = np.random.rand(100)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(d1)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,110,10),['']*11)
plt.xlim((0,100))

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(d2)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0,110,10),['']*11)
plt.xlim((0,100))
```

[image]

Comment: Is this specific to having 10 major ticks though? Is there a way to do this more generally?

Comment: Now, i fixed it. Number of empty strings should be equal to number of ticks of course.

Comment: This still rescales my y-axis and does not actually remove tick labels.

Comment: In this case you need to set limits to your y-axis, I added that in the answer.

Comment: If I use ax.set_xlim((xi, xf)) to redefine my axis, it still rescales my axis in an unwated way and now also removes all my data from the plot. Also, the ax.set_xticks(x_ind, ['']*len(xind)) method does not actually remove tick labels.

Comment: When you use `plt.subplot` you don't necessarily have to assign it to a value. You can set the ticks and the limits for axes from `plt` (pyplot) object. It sounds weird that it removes all your data from the plot, what backend are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164790/discussion-between-relay-and-tptptpfg).