# For a Matplotlib plot, how do I hide the tick marks but keep the tick labels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

When creating a 2-D plot in Matplotlib, what method hides the tick marks/lines but not the labels?  I want the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48695269/remove-tick-labels-but-not-tick-marks-but-preserve-distance-beween-ticks).  I do not see an appropriate method in the [Matplotlib API](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#ticks-and-tick-labels).

As a hack, I have considered "hiding" the tick marks by setting the color to match the background (e.g., white).  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6):

The appropriate method to manipulate the ticks is [`.tick_params()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params).

Here you want to turn the ticks off, but not the labels, hence

```
ax.tick_params(axis="x", bottom=False)
```

for a single axis, or

```
ax.tick_params(left=False, bottom=False)
```

for both axes.